# One quarter section is cut from a uniform circular disc: Moment of Inertia

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

[image]

One-quarter section is cut from a uniform circular disc of radius R like I showed in the picture. What happens to the moment of inertia?

We know that moment of inertia of a solid disc is:

$$I=\frac{1}{2}MR^2$$

The center of mass of the remaining part changes. That's why I thought we can't subtract the moment of inertia of the removed part from the moment of inertia of the complete disc. Am I right about this?

How can we find the moment of inertia of the remaining part of the disc?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the moment of inertia of the three-quarters disc *about the centre of the original disc* then you can just subtract the moment of inertia of the quarter disc about this same point. So you are left with three quarters of the moment of inertia of the original disc.

If you want to find the moment of inertia of the three-quarters disc *about its centre of mass* then you need to find the location of the centre of mass of the three quarters disc and then use the [parallel axis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem).